# c++ exception(std::bad_alloc) handle in objc++

Tags: c++, objective-c, exception

As title, throw exception in c++:

```
class TestCpp
{
public:
    TestCpp (){
        NSLog(@"TestCpp init.");
        throw "simple exception."; // or throw std::bad_alloc();
    }
    ~TestCpp(){
        NSLog(@"TestCpp fini.");
    }
};
```

And catch it like this:

```
@try{
    TestCpp o;
}
@catch(NSException* ex) {
    NSLog(@"exception: %@", ex.reason);
}
@catch(...){
    NSLog(@"unknown exception.");
}
```

But that can not work. 
Moreover, in objc++, if no way to handle a exception thrown by C++, how can we handle C++ instance construct exceptions, like std::bad_alloc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a *long* time investigate, I get some code:

```
Type* obj_ptr = new (std::nothrow) Type;
if(obj_ptr==nullptr) {
    @throw NSMallocException;
}
......
```

And so everything OK. Because NSMallocException has been initialized as process startup.
Some other resource acquire failure can handle as follow:

```
Resource* resource_handle = acquire(Resource);
if(resource_handle==nullptr) {
    @throw NSXxxGenericException;
}
......
```

Or you can initialize some special NSXxxException for your custom need.

Answer (score 0):

Most Objective-C libraries (esp. UIKit) do not support exceptions and their use is strongly discouraged by Apple. Catching exceptions in Objective-C code can lead to various bugs.

If you want to use C++ code in your Objective-C class then you have to use Objective-C++ by naming the file `.mm` instead of `.m`

Comment: `.mm` and `.m with compile as ObjC-C++` are both fine. But if C++ construct exception such as **std::bad_alloc()** cannot handled, something like **RAII** is boring and ugly, or I must setup some borderline cross these languages.